docxtpl duplicate render data in for loop
I have an API in Django Rest Framework and encountered an issue with docxtpl. I'm using a template to be filled by a single render with a global context, converting the file to PDF, and sending it to my frontend to download the file. However, if I try to use the function more than once, the initially filled file has its data duplicated within the for loop of the template document. In other words, a table that is filled with a for loop in the template, which initially has one filled row, ends up with two duplicate rows. I think it has something to do with the render function. At some point, I thought I had solved it by setting the is_rendered flag to false before using the render function. It worked when I tested it, but I had tried so many things before that I have no idea what really solved it. When I shut down the Django server, it returns to normal. This means that the filled document works well when I try to download it for the first time, but it still doesn't work on the second attempt.
with io.BytesIO() as temp_docx_buffer:
        with open("myapp/doc/Modelo_RADOC.docx", 'rb') as file:
            conteudo_arquivo = file.read()

            with io.BytesIO() as arquivo_em_memoria:
                arquivo_em_memoria.truncate(0)
                arquivo_em_memoria = io.BytesIO(conteudo_arquivo)
                doc = DocxTemplate(arquivo_em_memoria)

        temp_docx_buffer.truncate(0)
        doc.is_rendered = False
        doc.render(global_context)
        doc.save(temp_docx_buffer)
        html_content = docx_to_html(temp_docx_buffer.getvalue())
        pdf_binary = convert_html_to_pdf(html_content)
    lista_atividades_letivas_1.clear()
    return pdf_binary

first download:
enter image description here
second download:
enter image description here
I made some modifications to the function, such as using the file entirely in memory. I also attempted to use Django's never_cache, clearsession, and even tried using a middleware to clear the session. Lastly, you experimented with setting the flag is_rendered = False
 Git Hub Project 
